# JavaScript Onclick is not working in Firefox26& 27. But working in Firefox5 & 12. Why?

Tags: javascript, firefox, yii, yui

I have used below code in Yii framework under protected/view/form to click action for td element. its not working in Firefox 26, but it is fine with Firefox version 5 & 12. Javascript is enable in 26. I don't know why? Please help to fix this issue.

```
      <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/yui-min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      YUI().use('node', function(Y) {
       var lis = Y.Node.all('#demo table tr td');
    var onClick = function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.setStyle('background', '#FFA100'); // e.container === #demo

    var crm_field_id=e.currentTarget.get('id');
    var tab=document.getElementById('tab_id').value ;
    window.location = "?crm_field_id=" + crm_field_id+"&tab="+tab;


    };      
    lis.each(function(v, k) {
    v.delegate('click', onClick, 'td');  

     });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Does firebug not tell you anything?

Comment: No it doesn't tell anything in console

Comment: I tried "Restart with Add-ons Disable"(Safe Mode) option. But this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have changed YUI onclick to JQuery onclick. Its works fine in all browsers and different version.

```
<script> 
var $tds = $('#demo table tr td');
$('#demo table tr td').click(function(e){

var num = $tds.index(this) + 1; 
 var crm_field_id=$(e.target).attr('id');
var tab=document.getElementById('tab_id').value ;
    window.location = "?crm_field_id=" + crm_field_id+"&tab="+tab;

  ......
  ......
  ......
}
</script>
```